# Singly Linked List Changes Not Sticking?

Tags: c++, function, linked-list

I am having a problem making changes to my linked list. This is what I have so far

```
struct node 
{
  char suit;
  int value;
  node* next;
};

//Fill out the list with 52 playing cards
void fillWithCards(node *&head, node *&tail, node *&now, node *&temp)
{
  char suits [] = {'s', 'h', 'd', 'c'};
  int val [] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14};
  vector <int> rand;

  for (int i = 0 ; i < 14 ; i++)
    rand.push_back(i);

random_shuffle (rand.begin(), rand.end());

srand(time(NULL));

for (int x = 0; x < 4 ; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0 ; y < 13 ; y++)
    {
        node *now = new node;
        now -> suit = suits [x];
        now -> value = val [y]; //rand.at(y)

        if (*&head == NULL && *&tail == NULL && *&temp == NULL)
        {               
            head = now;
            tail = now;
            temp = now;
        }
        else if (*&tail != NULL && *&temp != NULL)
        {
            tail -> next = now;
            temp -> next = now;
            tail = now;
            temp = now;
        }
        else 
        {
            tail -> next = NULL;
        }
     }
  }
}

//Print the list 
void print(node *head)
{
node *n = head;
while (n)
{
    cout << n-> suit;
    cout << n-> value << ", ";
    n = n -> next;
 }
}

//Remove the head of the list 
void removeHead (node *head)
{
  node *h = head;

  head = head -> next;
  h -> next = NULL;


  delete h;

  print (head);
}
```

The problem is that for example if I were to call my function to remove the head, it would do it, and I can call my print function in the `removeHead` and it would print out the change.

However, if I were to call the print function in `main` after calling `removeHead` instead of printing out the changed list it would instead print out the original list.

So I have a feeling that with my parameter of my `removeHead` it is making a copy of my list and changing the copied one instead of the actual list. But, I do not know for sure.

Comment: Just like in `fillWithCards` you need to pass the `node*` by reference for the changes to be seen in the calling function.

Comment: try void removeHead(node *&head) instead and see if it works :)

Comment: @NathanOliver & Kattie, Thank you!!! it worked. I am still trying to wrap my head around the whole passing by reference and passing by pointer.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this: `*&head`? It's the same as writing `head`. You're dereferencing the address of `head` which is the same as the value of `head`.

Comment: @NathanOliver glad it worked, when you don't pass by reference you are only passing a pointer to the variable location in the memory ... at least that's how I understand it :)